# How can I Set grub time off?

Tags: grub2

I have Kubuntu 17.04 and some other operating system and whenever I want to choose between these OS, the grub have timer about 10s,and if I do not choose one, grub choose defult operating system, Now how can I set this timer off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

now change `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to `-1`

save the file

run `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the system to boot into the default OS without showing the grub menu and without any delay, edit `/etc/default/grub` and set these variables:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

Then run `sudo update-grub`.